LaTeX Workshop in VS Code Not Rendering Equations Properly
When using the LaTeX Workshop extension in Visual Studio Code, a white rectangle appears as a tooltip when hovering over LaTeX code (e.g., \begin{equation} environments). Instead of showing a rendered preview of the equation, the tooltip displays a white box that does not provide any rendered output.

Steps to Reproduce:

Open a .tex file in VS Code with LaTeX Workshop installed.
Hover the mouse pointer over a LaTeX equation environment (e.g., \begin{equation} ... \end{equation}).
Observe that a white rectangle appears instead of the rendered equation.

If you want to use the above equation, here it is:
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:tangency-riskfree}
    \begin{aligned}
        \max_{\boldsymbol{w}} \quad & \frac{\boldsymbol{\mu}_P - r_f}{\sigma_P} \\
        \text{s.t.} \quad & \boldsymbol{w}^\top \boldsymbol{1} = 1\\
        & 0 \leq w_i, \quad \forall i
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Expected Behavior: The tooltip should display the rendered version of the LaTeX equation or provide a preview of how the equation will appear in the compiled document.
Actual Behavior: The tooltip shows a white rectangle, not the rendered equation.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified LaTeX Workshop settings in VS Code.
Ensured that the LaTeX document is properly built without errors.
Checked for updates to both VS Code and the LaTeX Workshop extension.
Restarted VS Code and tried various settings configurations.
Confirmed that other LaTeX features, such as building and viewing the PDF, are working correctly.

Additional Information:

The issue persists despite correctly configuring LaTeX Workshop and using supported file types (.tex).
Other LaTeX functionalities (like PDF rendering) are working as expected, but the tooltip preview is not functioning.

